# Is firefox can trace the file and its location

Tags: php, html, file, directory, frontend

I'm working on a project on localhost. Its kind of a company management application based on some php framework. Basically I'm a front-end developer and I've to fix some pages, their alignments and color scheme. I'm using firefox. Every single time when I've to change the settings of any page I've to go the php dev who built the app and they located file for me in the project, obviously they knew the file structure of the whole project. So is there any possible way, tool, addon or plugin that can identify the specific file (which is currently open in my browser) for me? so that I can reach the file on localhost directly and edit it right away rather than bothering the php developers all the time. Firefox inspect element can identify the css files though. Any help would be appreciated. Thanks

Comment: Unfortunately not Muhammad - especially if a framework is involved.  In most modern PHP frameworks, there could literally be dozens of files involved in the process of getting output to the browser.  IF it's a well-structured application built on a well-structured framework, you'll likely find that there will be a certain subset of directories which contain the files specifically involved in producing the *views* you're working with.  My suggestion would be that you ask the backend dev if such a subset of directories does indeed exist - at least you can narrow your search.

Comment: it based on Laravel framework.

Comment: In that case, there should indeed be a 'central' location for your view files (and dozens in the background responsible for other functionality).  Ask your backend dev to point out the location of the *views*.  With any luck, you'll find that the view files are named in such a way that their purpose will be readily apparent, and it shouldn't be TOO difficult to find what you need - even without intimate knowledge of the structure of the application.

Comment: thanks for appropriate guidance